# OpenGL: isampler2DArray vs. sampler2DArray vs. sampler3DArray

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm currently facing an issue with OpenGL samplers. I have a running fragment shader which uses a `isampler2DArray` variable to sample a stack of 2D images and an integer index which is used to retrieve the desired slice from the stack.

The fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 430

/* Per Fragment Input Attributes */
in vec2 texCoord;

/* Per Fragment Uniform Attributes */
layout (binding = 0) uniform isampler2DArray textureSampler;

/* Per Fragment Output Values */
layout (location = 0) out vec3 out_color;

uniform float windowCenter;
uniform float windowWidth;

uniform int texIndex;

void main()
{
    float value = float(texture(textureSampler, vec3(texCoord, texIndex)).r);

    float min = windowCenter - windowWidth / 2;

    value = (value - min) / windowWidth;

    out_color = vec3(value);
}
```

When I tried to change the sampler to `sampler2DArray` and the uniform variable to retrieve the data to `float`, I only get a black screen instead of the sampled texture. Similar for a `sampler3D`.

The texture setup code looks as follows:

```
m_texture= std::make_unique<Texture>(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, nullptr, sequence->width(), sequence->height(), sequence->images().size(), GL_R16I, GL_RED_INTEGER, 1, 0, GL_SHORT);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, sequence->width());

for (int i = 0; i < sequence->images().size(); i++)
{
    m_texture->UpdateTexture(sequence->images()[i]->data(), 0, sequence->images()[i]->width(), 0, sequence->images()[i]->height(), i, 1);
}

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
```

For `sampler2DArray` and `sampler3D`, I uploaded my `float` uniform the following way, according to this stackoverflow question ([OpenGL 3D Texture Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488254/opengl-3d-texture-coordinates)):

```
prg_texture3D->SetUniform("currentSliceTexCoord", (1.0f + 2.0f * currentSlice) / (2.0f * sequence->images().size()));
```

I'm puzzled why the program runs with the `isampler2DArray` and not with the other two. Can you please make clear to me the difference between them, especially between `isampler2DArray` and `sampler2DArray`?

Comment: Where does the texture class come from? Did you set the min/mag filters correctly for the float textures?

Comment: It's a custom one I created myself. Both values are set to `GL_LINEAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> GL_R16I, GL_RED_INTEGER
> ```

If you use non-integer samplers, then your texture's [image format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats) must [match that](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Sampler_types). It must be a floating point or normalized integer format. And `GL_R16I` is an integer format, not a float/normalized format.

Comment: Ok, my data is 12 bit DICOM data, is there some way to convert it to `float` in a shader?

Comment: @Schnigges: What's wrong with your current method of casting it to a `float`?